# How to include IEnumerables with Entity Query

Tags: c#

When I try to include an ICollection property, it works, but if I try to include Enumerable, it fails to do so. I'm trying to have Eager loading, may I ask how abouts do Eager load an IEnumerable.

Person.cs

```
public virtual ICollection<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
public virtual IEnumerable<Business> Businesses { get { return Ownerships.Where(x => x.Active).Select(ownership => ownership.Business); } }
```

My current code setup(lazy loading) that works

```
Entity = UnitOfWork.PersonRepository.Get(x => x.Id == id).First();
Entity.Businesses.ForEach(
            x =>
                SelectedBusinesses.Add(
                    Businesses.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == x.Id) ?? new BusinessDTO { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }));
```

what I tried to do - crashes

```
Entity = UnitOfWork.PersonRepository.Get(x => x.Id == id, includeProperties: new[] { "Ownerships", "Businesses"}).First();

Entity.Businesses.ForEach(
            x =>
                SelectedBusinesses.Add(
                    Businesses.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == x.Id) ?? new BusinessDTO { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }));
```

[image]

Comment: where are you setting Ownerships?

Comment: @arviman Ownership is getting lazy loaded.

Comment: Are you sure the "includeProperties" is working correctly? There's no lazy loading cuz of the First(). Just debug and see.

Comment: @arviman um.... As I stated above, includes works with ICollection and not IEnumerables. And it is being lazy loaded... I've debugged and now you can see from the image above.

Comment: Why is `Busniesses` virtual?  You're not loading it from the database, you're just creating it on-the-fly based on data in `Ownerships` so it's _always_ "lazy-loaded".

Comment: Ownerships has an item in it..How's it lazy loaded? Please read up on it again.

Comment: @arviman I think you need to read up on lazyloading again and look up what ProxyCreation is.

Comment: lazy loading occurs for navigation properties. your obj. explicitly defines relationship btwn Ownership and Businesses.